# Calling MS Graph with delegated privileges doesn't work while application privileges do

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I try to get a user's custom attribute using a graph api call :

I have setup an app registration with `User.ReadWrite.All` **Delegated privileges** as stated in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and ***Granted admin privileges***:

[image]

Using python, I can fetch a token using my app registration secret :

```py
def retrieve_token(endpoint, client_id, client_secret):
    # endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token"
    payload = {
        "grant_type":"client_credentials",
        "client_id": client_id,
        "client_secret": client_secret,
        "resource":"https://graph.microsoft.com"
    }
    r = requests.request("POST", endpoint,data=payload).json()["access_token"]
    return r # returns a valid jwt token
```

Using that token I then call a function to get my user's attributes :

```py
def get_user_role(endpoint,user_uid, token):
    # endpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/"
    url = endpoint + user_uid 
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token, 
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    return requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers).json()
```

For some reason, it lacks of privileges :

```
{'error': {'code': 'Authorization_RequestDenied', 'message': 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.', 'innerError': {'date': '2022-03-29T16:11:38', 'request-id': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'client-request-id': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx'}}}
```

If I go back to my api's permissions and change the `User.ReadWrite.All` from **Delegated permissions** to **Application permissions** it works.

From what I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404128/azure-ad-app-application-permissions-vs-delegated-permissions) in this scenario I should use Delegated permission but how to get that to work?

Comment: Delegated permissions only work when a user is involved in the authentication process. You'll have to change the way you get access tokens to use e.g. authorization code flow or device code flow to get an access token as a signed in user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the `client credentials follow`(Authenticating using Client ID and Client Secret) so you should require to `Application permissions` to get token and call a function to get my user's attributes. So it won't Possible to calling an API with Client Crendetial Token using delegated permissions.

- As **junnas** stated in comment is correct **You typically use delegated permissions when you want to call the Web API as the logged on user.**
- **Application Permissions: Your application needs to access the web API directly as itself (no user context).**

**So you should change the way to get the access token use e.g. authorization code flow or device code flow to get an access token as a signed in user**

***You can refer this [**Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-username-password?tabs=dotnet) can help Desktop app that calls web APIs: Acquire a token using Username and Password***